# Woocommerce get products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used the following code to get the list of product categories form WooCommerce in my WordPress website:

```
 <?php
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title,
  'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
?>
<?php $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

//print_r($all_categories);
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    //print_r($cat);
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;

?>     

<?php       

        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>'; ?>


        <?php
        $args2 = array(
          'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
          'child_of'     => 0,
          'parent'       => $category_id,
          'orderby'      => $orderby,
          'show_count'   => $show_count,
          'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
          'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
          'title_li'     => $title,
          'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo  $sub_category->name ;
            }

        } ?>



    <?php }     
}
?>
```

This works fine and returns the list of product categories. I have been trying now to get a list of products for a particular category.

**Example**: get all the products for with `cat_id=34`.

I know products are stored as posts, and have been trying to get this done but can't seem to.

How do I get the list of products for a particular category?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
<?php  
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'product_cat'    => 'hoodies'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This will list all product thumbnails and names along with their links to product page. change the category name and posts_per_page as per your requirement.

Comment: Use 'product_cat' => $sub_category->slug  if you want to use this in the nested inner loop in your code.

Comment: Some of your guys out there are just genius. There should be a way of rewarding extremely helpful comment/people :)

Comment: I want to use `get_posts( arg)`. How I can do it ?

Comment: This way you get post objects, if i wanted to get product objects what should i use?

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 88):

Do not use `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`. From the WooCommerce doc:

> wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query provide a standard way of retrieving products that is safe to use and will not break due to database changes in future WooCommerce versions. Building custom WP_Queries or database queries is likely to break your code in future versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better performance.

You can retrieve the products you want like this:

```
$args = array(
    'category' => array( 'hoodies' ),
    'orderby'  => 'name',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

[WooCommerce documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

*Note: the category argument takes an array of slugs, not IDs.*

Comment: This doesn't work with ID of category. It expects the category slug.

Comment: @Himadri You seem to be right. The documentation only mentions slugs. I will amend the example.

Answer (score 26):

```
<?php
$args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'category' => 34, 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$products = get_posts( $args ); 
?>
```

This should grab all the products you want, I may have the post type wrong though I can't quite remember what woo-commerce uses for the post type. It will return an array of products

Comment: I have tried your snippet but it return only 5 products although I tried `post_per_page = -1`. can you tell me why ?

Comment: @huykon225 The correct parameter would be `posts_per_page`, not `post_per_page`.

Comment: @huykon225 No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Always use tax_query to get posts/products from a particular category or any other taxonomy. You can also get the products using ID/slug of particular taxonomy...

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'accessories',
        )
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    the_title(); echo "<br>";
endwhile;


wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please add explanatory text, why this answers the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer