# WooCommerce: function that returns all product ID's in a particular category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I think the title of the question is fairly self-explanatory, but to detail it...

I'm trying to make a custom category page in Woocommerce.

What I need is to return all the product ID's in a particular category.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028830/woocommerce-get-products), but it uses the WP_Query way of doing things, which is pretty ugly.

I'd prefer to use something in the WooCommerce classes to accomplish this.

Ideally, there should some sort of function/method like the following (but I can't find it):

```
get_products_in_category( $category_ID );
// Returns array of product ID's
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function get_products_ids_from_category_by_id( $category_id ) {

    $products_IDs = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids', 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_id,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )
        )
    ) );

    return $products_IDs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nabil. Saved my day. Is using WP_Query a preferred way to get custom information from Wordpress.

Comment: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is pretty much **the** way to get posts from the database. @nabil-kadimi you don't need the `foreach()` loop. You can modify your query to return only the IDs via the `"fields" => "ids"` query parameter.

Comment: @3Dom you'll be fine using WP_Query, [the beast you must avoid is query_posts()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/17187)

Comment: @NabilKadimi done! Hope that works, but it seems like it should.